# Java & OpenCV can't convert RGB .gif image to GRAY

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, rgb, gif

I want to convert pictures using Java and OpenCV from RGB to GRAY

All extensions images work correctly and I take the gray image,

just if I make .GIF image (not moving)  it's give me this error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor`

the java code :

```js
Mat scrImg = Highgui.imread(path);
Mat dstImg = new Mat(scrImg.rows(),scrImg.cols(),scrImg.type());
Imgproc.cvtColor(scrImg, dstImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

private static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat matrix){
 BufferedImage bimOut;
 int type;
 if(matrix.channels() == 1)
  type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
  
 else 
  type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
 
 int dataLength = matrix.channels()*matrix.cols()*matrix.rows();
 byte [] buffer = new byte[dataLength];
 bimOut = new BufferedImage(matrix.cols(),matrix.rows(),type);
 matrix.get(0,0,buffer);
 final byte[] bimPixels = ((DataBufferByte) bimOut.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
 System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bimPixels, 0, buffer.length);
 
 return bimOut;

}
```

Comment: can you test whether tje src image was loaded successfully? Can you output src.channels?

Comment: When I add a .gif image, it's loaded successfully, but the problem is when I want to convert it to the GRAY image

Comment: can you output/print the number of channels of the source image?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but do you mean matrix.channels() ? or scrImg ?

Comment: the one that is used as source im cvtColor where your code crashes.

Comment: My code crashed before `Imgproc.cvtColor` So my code does not arrive to the function, so I make `System.out.pritln` to the scrImg and I try the .png and .gif image, when I make .png It give me `Mat [ 803*1199*CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x19453f60, dataAddr=0x19a5f050 ]` but when I make .gif give me the : `Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x19773f60, dataAddr=0x0 ]`

Comment: There's the problem. The gif could not be loaded correctly, it is 0x0 resolution.

Comment: @Micka but the problem the .gif is not animated, just a simple picture has .gif extension is there any solution the change her extension to .png automatically ?

Comment: use a different library to load gif images. You can still convert typically any loaded image in your memory to an openCV matrix.

Comment: You can try the [freeimage library](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) though I have not tried it myself so there is no guarantee that it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)

> Currently, the following file formats are supported:
>
> - Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
> - JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
> - JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
> - Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
> - WebP - *.webp (see the Notes section)
> - Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm *.pxm, *.pnm (always supported)
> - Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
> - TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)
> - OpenEXR Image files - *.exr (see the Notes section)
> - Radiance HDR - *.hdr, *.pic (always supported)
> - Raster and Vector geospatial data supported by Gdal (see the Notes section)

Apparently support is not included Because gif is a proprietary format.
http://answers.opencv.org/question/72134/cv2imread-cannot-read-gifs/

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) seems a bit more authoritative source of information rather than some comment on a question.

Comment: Agreed. I'm using my phone right now so I kinda have to go with the first thing I find. I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: But I can learn the .gif image but I can't convert it to gray, this's the problem